# Cosa sono gli "impiastri di convento" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Violante, saputa, adulatrice che vuol essere adulata, mi mostrava certi suoi *impiastri di convento*, certi santini divoti, lei che rideva di tutto: voleva elogi, umiliandosi falsamente.

Quella che dice queste parole è la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi, quindi l'espressione "impiastri di convento" potrebbe avere qualcosa a che vedere con la pittura. La stessa Artemisia spiega un poco prima di questa Violante e altre donne di Firenze:

> tutte mi suplicavano di insegnar loro la pittura e il disegno, ma in segreto.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "impiastri di convento" nel brano precedente? Si riferisce forse all'[accezione **2.b** del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impiastro/), cioè a un "lavoro mal fatto, mal riuscito" che sarebbero questi "santini divoti" menzionati nel testo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credo che quello citato sia proprio il significato dell'espressione in oggetto. 
Il termine "impiastro" viene utilizzato come [sinonimo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impiastro_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) di *pasticcio*, *pastrocchio*.

Violante, in cerca di elogi, mostra queste opere indegne di soggetto religioso ad Artemisia, inconsapevole dello scarso valore del suo lavoro: quel che ne riceve, però, è null'altro che biasimo da parte della pittrice, che vede in questi «santini divoti» solo un'accozzaglia di colori e forme.

---

Della stessa radice di *impiastro* è il verbo [impiastrare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impiastrare/) (o anche [impiastricciare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impiastricciare_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)):

> Spalmare, o anche insudiciare, imbrattare, con materia untuosa o vischiosa [...] Spreg.: *i. la tela*, **di pittore che distende male i colori** (anche *i. i colori*); *i. i fogli, le carte*, con riferimento a cattivo scrittore.